# Catastrophic Failure in Delphi XE4 while calling DLL function

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

I am getting "Catastrophic Failure" error in following scenario.

```
type
TGetDoubleValue = function (var ID: Integer): Double; safecall;
....
....
var
GetDoubleValue: TGetDoubleValue;
.....
.....
LibHandle := LoadLibrary('GetDoubleValue.dll');
@GetDoubleValue := GetProcAddress(LibHandle, 'getDoubleValue');
if not (@GetDoubleValue = nil) then
begin
  myDouble := GetDoubleValue(ID);
end
else
  RaiseLastOSError;
```

I am getting error on the "`myDouble := GetDoubleValue(ID);`" line while calling this function.

Comment: I'm sure you'll acknowledge, this is somewhat different from your original version of this question. Your original was completely unanswerable. I'd like to suggest that it would be much more respectful of the time others will spend helping you to put a little more effort into asking a good question the first time around.

Comment: @CraigYoung - Thanks for your suggestion. I will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Almost certainly this error is because of a calling convention or parameter list mis-match.

It is highly unlikely that the function you import from the DLL really is `safecall`. That calling convention is used with COM methods to perform `HRESULT` parameter list re-writing. Much more plausible is that the calling convention is `stdcall`, but you must check. You should also double-check that the parameters and return type are an exact match.

If you cannot work it out for yourself, then please just add to the question the function's declaration from the DLL source code (or documentation).

I am also not a fan of using `@` with function pointers. It tends to lead to errors that could have been found by the compiler. I would write your code like this:

```
LibHandle := LoadLibrary('GetDoubleValue.dll');
Win32Check(LibHandle<>0);
GetDoubleValue := GetProcAddress(LibHandle, 'getDoubleValue');
Win32Check(Assigned(GetDoubleValue));
myDouble := GetDoubleValue(ID);
```

FWIW, I'm a huge fan of `Win32Check` because it removes branching from the high level code which makes it much easier to read.

Comment: If I were you I'd be wanting a bit more than trial and error. Do you have the declaration of the other function handy?

Comment: I have 3 functions declared with safecall and all are causing  same problem.

Comment: Can you show the declaration of `getDoubleValue` from the DLL's source code?

Comment: I am not able to open this dll. This is UDFPricing.dll installed with Firebird at path C:\Program Files (x86)\Firebird\Firebird_2_5\UDF

Comment: Where is it documented?

Comment: I mean, I have a hunch that these functions are actually `cdecl`.

Comment: I cannot find its documentation. Actually saw this dll today only when I got the error.

Comment: So who wrote the code that calls this function? To be honest, it does not look like it is part of Firebird at all. I think it came from within your organisation.

Comment: Yes, its not a standard dll. I have realized it too. It was just placed there and referred from there. I don't know what is the reason for that. It is very old code and don't know who wrote it. I am just correcting this error.

Comment: It would appear to be a Firebird UDF. Anyway, I think there's nothing more that I can do. I've identified the problem.

Comment: So, finally should I replace safecall with stdcall?

Comment: I cannot be sure. Either `stdcall` or `cdecl` seem most likely. It is not possible for us to say. We need more info. Only you can get that info.

Comment: Firebird UDFs should be exported stdcall.

Comment: @Andy_D The examples at sourceforce use `cdecl` so far as I can tell. Where are you getting your info from? Not that I am doubting it, it's just nice to have a reference.

Comment: The documentation at http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/writing-udfs-in-delphi-for-interbase-firebird/ states otherwise.

Comment: @Andy_D Thanks! *The compiler of IB also uses the stdcall calling convention so that is the right one to use* is conclusive. The example I found must have applied the calling convention through some means that I could not see.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You're welcome. But the documentation here http://www.ibphoenix.com/resources/documents/how_to/doc_307 states it should be cdecl! Arghh!! So much for consistency! Unless it has changed between versions? Early Firebird was a fork of Interbase 6.0 but has since been completely re-written.

Comment: @Andy_D Given that Firebird targets many platforms other than Windows, isn't `cdecl` more likely?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You're right that cdecl would make more sense, but I've long given up expecting sense from pretty much anything any more!